# Christoffel symbols with mixed indices

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I've just begun taking a graduate course in General Relativity and I came across the Christoffel symbols which we know are defined as:

$$\Gamma_{cab}=\frac{1}{2}(g_{ca,b}+g_{cb,a}-g_{ab,c})$$

for a given metric $g_{\mu\nu}$, which have all indices as covariant. However, I've also seen the Christoffel symbol with mixed indices (which we'll call of 2nd kind) as:

$$\Gamma^{c}_{ab}=\frac{1}{2}g^{kc}(g_{ak,b}+g_{bk,a}-g_{ab,k})$$

and after that a claim that the following identity holds if two of them are equal,

$$\Gamma^{a}_{a b}=\frac{1}{2}g^{ak}g_{ak,b}$$

which can only be true if the two last terms cancel, that is,

$$g^{ka}g_{bk,a}=g^{ka}g_{ab,k}=0$$

However, I've done the calculations with the known given tensor rules and this doesn't give lead to zero, so I would like to know if you've seen this derivation or if it's just a textbook error.

On the other hand, do the Christoffel symbols of the 2nd kind have a different geometrical interpretation than the original Christoffel symbols?

Comment: For the identity to hold, do you really need $g^{ka}g_{bk,a}=g^{ka}g_{ab,k}=0$? or is $g^{ka}g_{bk,a}=g^{ka}g_{ab,k}$ sufficient? (And remember the summation convention: $\Gamma^a_{ab}$ has an implied sum over $a$.)

Comment: It can also work with $g^{ka}g_{bk,a}=g^{ka}g_{ab,k}$ (because of the minus sign), but due to derivatives being taken with respect to different variables they're clearly different as far I see. I also agree about the implied summation over $a$ due to repeated indices, although the final form of the symbols in the case will depend on the given metric.

Comment: Sums are implied over all allowed values of both $a$ and $k$. If you take this into account when comparing the derivatives, does the relationship $g^{ka}g_{bk,a}=g^{ka}g_{ab,k}$ seem more plausible?

Comment: You're right, I forgot that there's also an implicit summation over $k$, so that means we have two implicit summations: one for $a$ and $k$. Since the summation is over all possible values of $a$ and $k$ (and both $a$ and $k$ can choose from the same values, i.e. there's no restriction on them for a given space), by expanding the sum we essentially will have the same terms both on the left side and right side, so they're equal. Am I correct? Edit: I wrote all the terms for a 3D space and indeed, I've got the same for both sides.

Comment: Yup, that's correct.  And your comment explains it nicely!

Comment: Thank you very much, I see that's sometimes it's useful to actually write the terms to check the solutions.

Comment: You shouldn’t have to write out the terms in the double sum to see this. It follows from the symmetry of the metric tensor.